# Second view not appearing within view controller

Tags: xcode, swift

I have just set up two views within a view controller and I am trying to switch from one view to another when a button is pressed. For some reason when I push the button, it seems that one view disappears as intended, however the other does not appear in it's place.

I have IBOutlets for both views - budgetDisplayView, budgetEntryView

When the button is pressed, this code is ran:

```
        budgetEntryView.hidden = true
        budgetDisplayView.hidden = false
```

I assumed it would be as simple as that, however I just get a blank screen when the button is pressed.

Any ideas as to why the second view is not appearing?

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the `budgetDisplayView`. Try making it visible in Interface Builder and run and see if you can see it even then. Also make sure you didn't actually put it inside the other view; if you did, hiding one will hide the other. (If this were not Swift, I would guess that the IBOutlet never got hooked up correctly, but I think Swift won't let you make that mistake; if `budgetDisplayView` was nil, you'd get a helpful crash.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was sure I had checked that the budgetDisplayView was not within the budgetEntryView but it turns out that it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `viewA` is containing `viewB` so when you hide `viewA` it is also hiding `viewB`.

[image]

So as above image when you hide `redView` it will hide `blueView` also

[image]

It should be in same herirachy like above image.In this case if you hide `redVew` and not hide `blueView` than only `redView` is hidden,`blueView` remains visible.If you move view in Interface Builder it automatically add as subView to below view in InterfaceBuilder.Use instead `size Inspector` to position views in interface builder in cases like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was sure I had checked that the budgetDisplayView was not within the budgetEntryView but it turns out that it was.